# Question Search Feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I routinely find that the "questions that may already have your answer" list when I am writing a question is a significantly better searching tool than the search bar. For instance, just now I searched for  "non-noetherian ring with noetherian zariski topology" in the search bar and got three rather unhelpful results. However, when I go to ask a question with that title, the second result I get is precisely the question I want.

Is there an explanation or deliberate reason for this? Why don't we just use the algorithm for the "questions that may already have your answer" feature for the search bar. I can imagine a situation where someone has a question, looks for it using the search bar and can't find the answer. He/she then posts the question without paying too much attention to the "questions that may already have your answer" since he/she has already searched for an answer and ends up posting a repeat that wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been discussed on network-wide Meta, e.g., [Related questions in "Ask Question" page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20432/) and [Search box vs Question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5167/). However, it's hard to know how much of this applies now because the search engine of the site has been evolving over time.

You may want to upvote  the popular feature request: [Link up the excellent search engine that gives "Questions that may already have an answer" with the search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187773/)

You are right that the built-in search bar is not very helpful<sup>[1]</sup>. Many users, myself included, use site-restricted Google search instead: see [How to efficiently use Google to search Math.SE content?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13946//)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Unless one is searching for posts with particular parameters, like questions with a given tag and no answers, or closed negatively scored questions, etc.