# Searching for an answer on MSE

Tags: support, search

I'm searching for an excellent answer on MSE about the intuition/interpretation of the binomial coefficient in combinatorics which arrived at the expression $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ in two different ways. Unfortunately, I didn't upvote it at the time and my searches haven't lead me anywhere yet.

One of the forms presented was to interpret $\binom{n}{k} k!$ the same way as $\frac{n!}{n-k!}$ and compare both expressions. I'm trying to remember the other, because they looked great for teaching.

Comment: Was it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288546/combinatorial-interpretation-of-the-identity-n-choose-k-n-choose-n-k or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566252/proving-and-identity-combinatorially

Comment: Unfortunately not. The answer I'm looking for was the one chosen by the OP and it explicitly stated that he'd describe two different ways to understand the proof, with one of them being the one I described.

Comment: Maybe this?  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/565228/ Or this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119487/

Comment: OMG, thank you, 900!! It's your second link! How did you find it? Post it as an answer and i'll give you your kudos :D

Comment: I retagged as [tag:support]. Questions are tagged [tag:discussion] when they are meant to invite exchange of opinions; there is nothing to discuss here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was found: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119487/  using the approach described here: [How to efficiently use Google to search Math.SE content?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13946/)

Comment: If I did not miss something, the linked answer only says that we can use Google with restricting to `site:math.stackexchange.com`. (And also provides a bookmarklet for this.) In case you (or your browser history) remember it; may I ask what was the search query you used to find this particular question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I tried several things, one of which worked; by now there's no way to recall which one.