# Optimize search results

Tags: support, search

Searching for "how to represent a square as a matrix", Google's first hit was [perfect](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20represent%20a%20square%20as%20a%20matrix&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US751&oq=how%20to%20represent%20a%20square%20as%20a%20matrix&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.8720j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I only searched on Google after not seeing a good result on math.stackexchange's search result. Math.stackexchange has a great result, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314369/can-we-represent-a-square-using-a-single-matrix), but after looking through every single page of my initial search results, it was not present.

So my question is, can the search feature be optimized in such a way that searching for something like "how to represent a square as a matrix" would return result "Can we represent a square using a single matrix" to begin with and, additionally, on the first page of the results (preferably near the top of the result.)

I thought I've noticed something like this before but I never paid attention. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26415/178015) is actually really related to what I'm talking about. The answer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16419/178015) seems to indicate the search bar is evolving over time, but that was 2014. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13946/178015) seems like the only valid work around I may play with later- although doing manual searches on two different pages isn't that hard I guess.

Comment: See also [this question over physics meta SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8976/why-does-google-give-better-results-than-pse-search-about-pses-own-pages).